# Code design: Instance method with deeply nested conditionals, put in another instance method of the same class or put it in a function?

Tags: python, design-patterns, encapsulation

Suppose I have an instance method that contains a lot of nested conditionals. What would be a good way to encapsulate that code? Put in another instance method of the same class or a function? Could you say why a certain approach is preferred?

Comment: If the code makes sense outside of the class, why not put there? Why don't you show some code, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function is only used by one class, and especially if the module has more classes with potentially more utility functions (used only by one class), it might clarify things a bit if you kept the functions as static methods instead to make it obvious which class they belong to. Also, automated refactorings (using the e.g. the rope library, or PyCharm or PyDev etc) then automatically move the static method along with the class to wherever the class is moved.

**P.S.** `@staticmethod`s, unlike module-level functions, can be overridden in subclasses, e.g. in case of a mathematical formula that doesn't depend on the object but does depend on the type of the object.

Comment: Also, this really has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: I set python as a keyword for in case someone would want to show an example they'd use python.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different questions here. The first one is what to do with multiple nested conditionals. There's no single right answer: it depends on your coding style, how the conditions interact, the architecture of your program and so on. Have a look at [this Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47789/how-would-you-refactor-nested-if-statements) question and [Jeff Atwood's blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) for some ideas; personally, I like

```
if not check1: return
code1

if not check2: return
code 2

...
```

although some people object to the multiple exit points.

---

The second question is what to do with individual functions if you're writing object oriented Python. The usual answer is just to put them as functions inside the module containing the class, since there's no requirement that a function be attached to a particular class. If you want, though, you can include them in the class as static methods.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I never have to use that 'to be encapsulated' piece of code anywhere else in my module. I think it would be clearer for people who read the code that it is not supposed to be used outside the class. I think I will put it in my class and make it a `_method()` instance method or a static method like you advised.